Configure space using gc in LaTeX
Using the new gc feature in Neovim 0.10, is there a way to configure how the adding comment is done, like "add comment symbol followed by space" instead of "add only comment symbol"?
latex
Original:
\documentclass{article}

Result of gc:
%\documentclass{article}

Desired result of gc:
% \documentclass{article}

python
Original:
import numpy

Result of gc:
# import numpy

as desired.

The behavior is controlled by the commentstring option.
To achieve what you want you should set the commentstring option to: % %s
:setlocal commentstring=%\ %s

To set that option for all LaTeX files a solution is to have a ~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim file with the following content:
setlocal commentstring=%\ %s

But if you have Treesitter installed, and the language you consider has a Treesitter parser installed, it injects the value of this option and you lose control.
This is the case for LaTeX and you can't change the behavior.
For more information see the corresponding documentation page:
You can install a commenting plugin to gain more control.
Here are some popular examples:

vim-commentary (authored by the prolific @tpope)
comment.nvim (included in LunarVim)
nerdcommenter (uses <Leader>cc)
tcomment_vim
vim-tag-comment (old but works very well for commenting tags)

More about that in the following question
